# React Native, IBECONS, RSSI value to distance conversion

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, distance, ibeacon, rssi

How to stabilize the ***RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indicator)*** of low energy ***Bluetooth beacons (BLE)*** for more accurate distance calculation?

We are trying to develop an indoor navigation system and came across this problem where the ***RSSI*** is fluctuating so much that, the distance estimation is nowhere near the correct value. We tried using an advance average calculator but to no use,

The device is constantly getting ***RSSI*** values, how to filter them, how to get the mean value, I am completely lost, please help.

Can anyone suggest any ***npm library*** or point in the right direction, I have been searching for many days but have not gotten anywhere.

***FRONT END: ReactNative BACKEND: NODEJS***

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer of @davidgyoung, we would like to point out that any filtering method is a compromise between quality of noise level reduction and the time-lag introduced by this filtration (depending on the characteristic filtering time you use in your method). As was pointed by @davidgyoung, if you take characteristic filtering period T you will get an average time-lag of about T/2.

Thus, I think the best approach to solve your problem is not to try to find the best filtering method but to make changes on the transmitter’s end itself.

First you can increase the number of signals, transmitter per second (most of the modern beacon allow to do so by using manufacturer applications and API).

Secondly, you can increase beacon's power (which is also usually one of the beacon’s settings), which usually reduces signal-to-noise ratio.

Finally, you can compare beacons from different vendors. At Navigine company we experimented and tested lots of different beacons from multiple manufacturers, and it appears that signal-to-noise ratio can significantly vary among existing manufacturers. From our side, we recommend taking a look at kontakt.io beacons (https://kontakt.io/) as an one of the recognized leaders with 5+ years experience in the area.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you will find a pre-built package that will do what you want as your needs are pretty specific.  You will most likely have to wtite your own filtering code.

A key challenge is to decide the parameters of your filtering, as an indoor nav use case often is impacted by time lag.  If you average RSSI over 30 seconds, for example, the output of your filter will effectively give you the RSSI of where a moving object was on average 15 seconds ago.  This may be inappropriate for your use case if dealing with moving objects.  Reducing the averaging interval to 5 seconds might help, but still introduces time lag while reducing smoothing of noise.  A filter called an [Auto-Regressive Moving Average Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387814/theory-behind-arma-and-running-average-filter-and-are-there-any-alternative-algo/37391517#37391517) might be a good choice, but I only have an implementation in Java so you would need to translate to JavaScript.

Finally, do not expect a filter to solve all your problems.  Even if you smooth out the noise on the RSSI you may find that the distance estimates are not accurate enough for your use case.  Make sure you understand the limits of what is possible with this technology.  I wrote [a deep dive on this topic here.](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2020/05/15/how-far-can-you-go)